# Android Material TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to check whether the Material TextField is empty or not. If it is empty, error should be enabled.
How to set error in Material TextField.
And if the text field is not empty how can I fetch the text from the Material TextField.

All this need's to be done in mainactivity.java

**myxml.xml**

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/text_input_project_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
android:hint="Project Name"
app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="15dp"
app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="15dp"
app:endIconMode="clear_text"
app:errorEnabled="true">
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/projectname_np"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try this: 
// for testing is text field is empty 
text_input_project_name.getText().equals("")
// for getting value from textfield.
String text = text_input_project_name.getText();

Comment: Please try with this: 

// Get input text
val inputText = filledTextField.editText?.text.toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a text field is empty, you can do this in your Java code -

```
if(textInputLayout.getText().toString().matches(""){
    // Do something
}
```

You can set the text in the TextInputLayout by using textInputLayout.setText() method in your MainActivity when you want to use it. [Check out the documentation here.](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/)